# material-UI: how to increase scrollbar size

Tags: reactjs, size, scrollbar, material-ui

I use react and material-UI for a touch screen application on a 7" raspi. There is a List (@material-ui/core/List) Element with more elements then available space. So List shows a scrollbar. But the bar itself is not big enough for a finger. Has anybody an idea how to customize its size?

BR
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mobile apps/ web apps (with touch interface), the scroling is achieved by touching and dragging the screen (upwards, downwards & sideways).

The scroll bar is just to show the current position of the content view.

I doubt if any user would actually use the scroll bars for scrolling on the touch screens.

Comment: you are right, thats works well. the only thing is that clients maybe don't get it and try to use this very small scrollbar...